# Check if a number already exist in a 2d list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a 2 dimensional list like this:
[[1,2],[2,5],[3,4]]

i want to check if i have 3 in my first dimension of list, it should return true. how do i do it in python?

Comment: Convert your list to array and `return 3 in arr[:,0]` which will be True if it exists else False

Comment: Flagged for low effort. Please, next time, when asking a question, try a little harder and include what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot/don't want to simply flatten the list:

Is `3` in any first element?

```
alist = [[1,2],[2,5],[3,4]] 
any([e[0] == 3 for e in alist]) # True
```

which is the matching element? (Note, this throws a `ValueError` if no match)

```
[e[0] == 3 for e in alist].index(True) # returns 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alist = [[1,2],[2,5],[3,4]] 

for i in alist:
    if 3 in i[0:]:
        print("TRUE")
>>>TRUE
```